# how to make the menu reappear in while loop

Tags: java, loops

How to make the menu reappear if the user doesnt press any key like 3 in this case to exit the program.

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class New {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println("Enter 1 to create folder/ 2 to create file/ 3 to exit");
        Scanner scan= new Scanner(System.in);
        int choice= scan.nextInt();
                while(true) {
                    if(choice==1) {
                        System.out.println("Creating folder");
                    }
                    else if(choice==2) {
                        System.out.println("Creating file");
                    }
                    else {
                        System.out.println("Exiting");
                    }


                }

    }
}
```

Comment: Use  do ... while loop.

Answer (score 1):

You have to put the System.out.println() statement inside the loop.

```
public class New {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner scan= new Scanner(System.in);
    while(true) {
      System.out.println("Enter 1 to create folder/ 2 to create file/ 3 to exit");
      int choice= scan.nextInt();
      if(choice==1) {
        System.out.println("Creating folder");
      }
      else if(choice==2) {
        System.out.println("Creating file");
      }
      else if (choice==3){
        System.out.println("Exiting");
      }
   }

}
```

Comment: Even more important: put the `int choice= scan.nextInt();` inside the loop.

Answer (score 0):

You can use do while loop.

```
do{
    choice = sc.nextInt();
    if(choice==1) {
        System.out.println("Creating folder");
    } 
    else if(choice==2) {
        System.out.println("Creating file");
    }
}while(choice!=3);
```

Comment: It results in an infinite loop as it would if we use only while loop

Comment: That's why it's a do while loop